# How SPARQL query processing to be done on cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, sparql

I would like to know how the SPARQL query processing has to be done on Cassandra cluster. For instance, I have stored the university data generated by LUBM on Cassandra cluster. Now I want to execute the below query on Cassandra nodes A, B, C, D and I handed this query to node A as this node is my main client node, which will be in synch with other nodes using Gossip protocol.

```
PREFIX ub: <http://www.lehigh.edu/~zhp2/2004/0401/univ-bench.owl#> 
SELECT ?X WHERE
{
  ?X a ub:student .
  ?Y a ub:graduateCourse .
  ?X ub:takesCourse ?Y .
}
```

My question is how the subparts of query to be executed on distributed Cassandra nodes? Does node A pass full query to all the nodes and get back results from every other node? or a part of query to be distributed to all the nodes and get intermediate results back, and again send second part so on..?

Comment: The example query OP gives is a SPARQL query. See http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra itself does not support the SPARQL query language. However, [CumulusRDF](http://code.google.com/p/cumulusrdf/) is an RDF database on top of Cassandra which does support SPARQL - it might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I created a SPARQL endpoint for Cassandra using Redland.

There's a Redland module for Cassandra here: https://github.com/cybermaggedon/cassandra-redland

Also, a wrapper for Redland which provides a SPARQL endpoint: https://github.com/cybermaggedon/sparql-service

I've packaged the SPARQL bit up as a Docker container:
https://hub.docker.com/r/cybermaggedon/sparql-cassandra/ the container command line arguments are:

`/usr/local/bin/sparql <PORT> cassandra <CASSANDRAHOSTNAME>`

Documentation is missing . If you're interested in any of this and can't work out how to get it to work, PM me, or raise an issue on github and I'll write the READMEs.